# How do I sharpen the image quality of a bitmap in my Android App?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I need to sharpen the image quality of an image in Android Studio.
The Source of the images is from a PDF file.

Note: When I zoom in on the page - the image sharpens and when I view the entire page in a single page, it is extremely blurry.

How can I sharpen the image quality using? I have read some articles on BitmapFactory, but I am not clear on how to implement it.
Also, is BitMap factory the best way for me to do this?

I am still fairly new to android and I am feeling my way around.
Any code examples and tips are greatly welcomed and appreciated.

*NOTE: I did use an example from the internet as I am teaching myself how to do this.*

Below is my code in the app:

```
 private void showPage(int index) {
        if (mPdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
            return;
        }

        if (null != mCurrentPage) {
            mCurrentPage.close();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCurrentPage.getWidth(), mCurrentPage.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        mCurrentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        updateUi();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if a change the original dpi settings of the PDF it renders nicely.